# Unable to publish app: Issue facing package name in android studio- Playstore

Tags: firebase, android-studio

I am facing an issue regarding android app. when I upload the app on google play it shows me error

> You need to use a different package name because "com.isbproperty" already exists in Google Play

[image]

I want to change to completely remove app with package name from google play. is there any option because I am unable to find to remove package name?

Comment: Have you previously added an app with the same package? If that's the case, you have to remove it.

Comment: yes thankyou done Alex , and please tell me how many days required for android app to publish in playstore.

Comment: It depends. If  you have a new account it may take a few days.

Comment: Yes I am new and I have added app on OCT 16,2021